# ERROR: ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: weblogic, oracle21c

```
Message icon - Error Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor 
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:443)
```

Hi Evreyone 
I've tried all suggestions here in this `(ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach))`
and the final result is the same as this error. I've been stuck here for 5 days, and I'm still unable to connect from Weblogic to the database. Please #assist me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: listener. ora
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = 2023))  )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.2)(PORT = 1521)))
    (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))))SID_LIST_XE =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\21c\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Administrator\product\21c\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr.dll")
    )
  )

Comment: tnsname.ora
  XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.1)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.2)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(Key = 123))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )